# How to name a collection of flags?

Tags: c#, enums

For example I have the following flag enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum Colors
{
    Red = 1,
    Green = 2,
    Blue = 4
}
```

According to [MS Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229058.aspx):

> DO name flag enums with plural nouns or noun phrases and simple enums with singular nouns or noun phrases.

So I've used plural form here. Now, there is [another guideline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012(v=vs.110).aspx) to name your collections in plural form:

> DO name collection properties with a plural phrase describing the items in the collection instead of using a singular phrase followed by "List" or "Collection."

I have a class something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public IEnumerable<Colors> Colors { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is it gets very confusing when I try to work with separate items in that collection - they're also `colors`.
So how should I name a collection of flags then?

**EDIT:**

Ok, the example is not very clear, I agree. Maybe this one is better:

```
[Flags]
public enum Operations
{
    TextFormatting = 1,
    SpellChecking = 2,
    Translation = 4
}

public class TextProcessingParameters
{
    public IEnumerable<Operations> Operations { get; set; }
    // other parameters, including parameters for different operations
}
```

After text processor has finished, it has several results - one for each `operations` in `Operations` collection (already confusing), e.g. one for `SpellChecking` AND `TextFormatting`, and another for `Translation` only.

Comment: What's the purpose of having a collection of flag enums?

Comment: Consider having an enum of operations. These operations maybe performed simultaneously or in parallel. And I have a collection of such enum values - operation1 and operaion2 run simultaneously and operation3 runs in parallel. Something like that.

Comment: Still don't see the purpose of a collection, since you can and/or flags...maybe a better example would help?

Comment: If each collection member is being processed separately (and as the OP notes possibly in parallel), why use bit logic to combine the flags, just to have to use bit logic to pull them apart again?  It could even be that an operation should be applied more than once (depending on the domain), which cannot be represented by combining bits.  The order of operations may also matter.

Comment: Then perhaps a collection of _operations_ with a enum _property_ would make more sense.  Or maybe it will be more clear to us if you use the _actual_ names rather than making up new ones.

Comment: @RufusL How to distinguish with single flag property between "operation1 THEN operation2" and "operation1 WITH operation2"?

Comment: @DStanley, you mean just a separate class with one enum property? Seems like an overhead...

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin if you are concerned with ordering, you should not be using flags.  Flags are a set of criteria.  "I am blue, red, and purple."  Back to the naming, I personally like to use the word "collection" if there is ambiguity between the two.  So, by default I am agreeing with DStanley.  +1

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin It's hard to say without knowing the _actual_ names, values, and purpose.   Guidelines are guidelines, not hard and fast rules, so they're breakable, but there's not a rule that says how to name collection of flag enums in all cases (probably because it seems like a special case).

Comment: @MatthewFrontino, using `collection` is not an option, unfortunately, cause it somewhat hides the fact that this is a collection. I thought of using `ColorFlags` maybe?

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin something doesn't feel right about what you are doing here.  Agreeing even more with DStanley.

Comment: @DStanley, I've added another sample, does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While agreeing with the question comments that something doesn't feel quite right, I'd suggest that if the enum name is chosen more carefully to reflect the "component" nature of each item it can represent, the problem seems to go away.

For example, the original renamed:

```
[Flags]
public enum ColorComponents
{
    Red = 1,
    Green = 2,
    Blue = 4
}

public class Foo
{
    public IEnumerable<ColorComponents> Colors { get; set; }
}
```

And the updated example renamed:

```
[Flags]
public enum OperationComponents
{
    TextFormatting = 1,
    SpellChecking = 2,
    Translation = 4
}

public class TextProcessingParameters
{
    public IEnumerable<OperationComponents> Operations { get; set; }
    // other parameters, including parameters for different operations
}
```

You can also take a slightly different approach by renaming the collection to reflect the compositional aspect of each item in the collection:

```
[Flags]
public enum Operations
{
    TextFormatting = 1,
    SpellChecking = 2,
    Translation = 4
}

public class TextProcessingParameters
{
    public IEnumerable<Operations> OperationSets { get; set; }
    // other parameters, including parameters for different operations
}
```

The first approach seems slightly cleaner, though.

Comment: Yeah, first approach seems for me better too.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect `Operations` to be a list of `Operation`, not a list of `Operations`. Unfortunately, you cannot pluralize `Operation` twice.

Thus, I'd take the pragmatic approach an invent a new word for your flag enum,  which is

- grammatically singular but
- still represents the *combination* of individual enum values rather than a single one of them.

For the sake of argument, let's call the enum `OpCombination` -- a combination of operations. Then you can name the list naturally:

```
public IEnumerable<OpCombination> OpCombinations { get; set; }
```

Comment: Well, since I have to break some guidelines anyway, I like this approach.